# Rails 3.1 set host in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, config

I'm getting `http://www.example.com` whenever I use `root_url` in my tests.

It works fine in development, where I have this in config/environments/development.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'
```

Adding this doesn't work in config/environments/test.rb, though. What should I add to use `localhost:3000` as the host in the test environment?

Comment: This is a common problem, see this thread: http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rspec-users/2012-January/021016.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing code that depends on `default_url_options` causes all kinds of problems, see [this thread](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rspec-users/2012-January/021016.html) and  this [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255) for examples.

I've solved the problem by patching `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` in tests to force rails to include defaults for whatever options I want (in my case `locale`). See my answer in the [github issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255#issuecomment-7858480) linked to above for details.

To override the `host` option using the same approach:

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def url_for_with_host_fix(options)
    url_for_without_host_fix(options.merge(:host => 'localhost:3000'))
  end

  alias_method_chain :url_for, :host_fix
end
```

Put this in a file in `support`, should do the trick.

Comment: Worked like a charm with `:host => 'localhost', :port => '3000'`.

Comment: Someone should write up a blog post or something on this problem sometime, it comes up so often... anyway glad the patch fixed it for you.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. My app has the routes correct, for some reason, but the test server appears to be not running, and I keep getting "connection refused" errors in my tests. Did that happen to you as well? Wondering how I'd establish connection with the test server...

Comment: This seems very much overkill for a configuration problem.